# Best approach to go from string input to task execution?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, embedded, sensors

I receive a string in my embedded application of format:

*SLP24h MES1x SLP1h MES2s100ms*

which translated would state:

sleep for 24 hours, then take sample measurement once, then sleep for 1 hour, then take measurements for 2 seconds every 100 millisecond.

I am to receive that and similar strings, and use them to generate a scheduling for sensor measurements. String is given by user at run-time, therefore must be processed during run-time. Language is C or C++. Platform is embedded ARM, running freeRTOS.

My initial plan is to look into grammar, intending to write my own, and use it to parse incoming string and generate structs from it (struct content would depend on parsed command). I'd place those structs into a vector, and the sensor measurement task would loop around that vector performing action after action.

Actions would probably be coded as events, so basically loop in the vector, read structs as requested action and perform actions using finite state machine.

However, I find myself overwhelmed by the task (simply reading about grammar is effortful), therefore I'd like to check my approach before I roll up my sleeves and get my hands dirty.

Would my approach be valid? Is there a more standard way to solve this type of problem? If someone could give advice on what a good starting point would be and list some useful reading material, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. Now break it down further. Keep making more simpler tasks out of bigger tasks until none of the many small tasks are intimidating.

Comment: The example commands you show are too simple to parse without any formal grammar.

Comment: Creating grammar is required of me, as it is planned to expand the commands list in the future.